# How can I assure not selected fields records at the checkbox won't be displayed at lookup?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I have a form and lookup field in it named PI Code. PI code comes from another table and this table has a checkbox field named active. MY lookup field needs to display only the active fields. How can I do that? If I copied onlookup event handler from the PI code and try to filter, how can I assure that inactive records won't be displayed? I would be really appreciated it if anyone can help me.

Thanks and regards...

[image: lookup filed]

[image: Parent table]

Comment: What type of lookup is this? Provide your code. You would just modify the lookup query to include a range/value of something like `[...].addRange(fieldNum(YourTable, Active).value(queryValue(NoYes::Yes));`

Comment: Glad to help, I'll change the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the lookup query to include a range/value of something like:

> `[...].addRange(fieldNum(YourTable, Active).value(queryValue(NoYes::Yes));`